# How to set Main Interface field blank?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I used MainWindow-iPad as Main Interface in my project. But now i set window dynamically in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
```

So i don't need any value in Main Interface field in iPad Deployment info. But when i try to clear this field it becomes MainWindow. But i use MainWindow.xib only for iPhone. I want to leave Main Interface blank. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a storyboard, the solution is to uncheck "Is Initial View Controller". The property in the deployment info will still be set, but launching it fails because it cannot find the default view controller in this storyboard.
Instead the code you execute yourself in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is executed, so that the result is the window will start with your intended interface.